# What is the the difference between `|x,y|` and `|x;y=0|` in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to understand the local variable creation inside the pipe(`|`) when writing code with block. And also tried the same in my `IRB` below codes.

```
[1,2,3].each {|x;y| y=x; print y}

#123=> [1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3].each {|x;y = 0| y=x; print y}

#SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '|'
#[1,2,3].each {|x;y = 0| y=x; print y}
                    ^
#(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
#        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

But couldn't understand what's happened with the second code,while the first one is perfect.

Could anyone tell me the difference between `|x,y| and |x;y=0|` ? Hope answer to this 
question will make sense to me.

Again below works perfectly:

```
a = "hello world".split(//).each{ |x,newstr = Array.new() | newstr = x.capitalize;puts newstr }

#H
#E
#L
#L
#O
#
#W
#O
#R
#L
#D
#=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Ruby 1.9, it is possible to declare **a local variable in a block** by separating it from block parameter with **`;`**. In your example, `x` is then a block parameter, and `y` is a local variable. The following code illustrates it well.

```
> [1,2,3].each {|x; y| puts "x: #{x} - y: #{y}"}
x: 1 - y: 
x: 2 - y: 
x: 3 - y:
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

As y is not initialized, it has no value. **Syntactically, you cannot init a local block variable directly between the pipes `| |`** as you did in your second example. It's just forbidden.

However, in Ruby 1.9, you can set **default value for block parameters**. Indeed,

```
> [1,2,3].each {|x,y=0| puts "x: #{x} - y: #{y}"}
x: 1 - y: 0
x: 2 - y: 0
x: 3 - y: 0
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

is syntactically correct. This time **`y` is a block parameter with default value `0`**. You can illustrate the difference with the following:

```
> { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}.each {|x,y=0| puts "x: #{x} - y: #{y}"}
x: one - y: 1
x: two - y: 2
x: three - y: 3
 => {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
```

Comment: Please see my update. Why then we are able to initialize the array object inside the `|`?

Comment: See my answer, you can set a default value for parameter block, not local variable block between `||`. That's why your last example is valid.

Comment: Okay! That means `method` is also block and it allows the default value syntax,but anonymous block doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by `method`? I mean that block parameter could have a default value such as `|x=0, y=1|`, but local block parameter couldn't be initialized to a value `|x; y=1|` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`;y` is used to work around Ruby's scoping (shadowing outer variables), and does not accept a value because it's inside `||`

Comment: That I know, But my question was what's the difference between `;y=0` and `;y` inside `|`. See my updated description.

Comment: That's just forbidden by Ruby.